# Edit <title> in bbPress homepage

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I want to do something like that:  `<title>Custom text...</title>`
On the bbPress homepage. I've spent hours looking for the answer and I can't find it...

I know that it's possible to create page and add shortcodes like here: https://codex.bbpress.org/features/shortcodes/
But in this case it doesn't work if my root slug for bbPress is the same like the page. If slug is different - I will have two homepages :/

Do anybody had similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this hook to execute your custom code top of the bbPress homepage.

```
'bbp_template_before_forums_index'
```

example:

```
add_action( 'bbp_template_before_forums_index', 'your_callback_function' );
function your_callback_function(){
  $output_html = '';
  $output_html .= "<title>Custom text...</title>";
  echo $output_html;
}
```

use this code in your functions.php file, i hope it'll help you.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't change anything. This is root for my bbPress http://wcag.exception.com.pl/forum-onkologiczne/ . Title attribute is still <title>Archiwum Fora - Zwrotnikraka</title> . Do you have different idea?